# Can somebody explain how to push files to github using ssh

Tags: github

I already have ssh keys i already used for one pushing repository. can somebody explain how to reutilize my existing ssh key for pushing github. Detailed process for using existing ssh key.

I have ssh key, but i am unable to push my repositories to github remotely. whenever I am trying to push, it is asking for username and password for 2 times. In the 2nd time the password will be the ssh key which is added in the github right!. But it is not working. Even though before I run ssh-agent command and ssh-add command in the project folder. Please help.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: I seen the documentation, I searched so many stackoverflow questions also I didnt find my query related answer. That's the only reason I posted this question.

Comment: I have ssh key, but i am unable to push my repositories to github remotely. whenever I am trying to push it is asking for username and password for 2 times. In the 2nd time the password will be the ssh key which is added in the github right!. But it is not working. Even though before I run `ssh-agent command` and `ssh-add command` in the project folder. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you forgot edit your config file to .ssh/
if it's the case:

vim config ( in .ssh )

Host github.com

Hostname github.com

User git

Port 22

Identityfile /home/$USER/.ssh/$yourprivatekeyforssh

You can test your connection with
ssh -T github.com

keep me posted on progress
bye

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check your remote URL

```bash
cd /path/to/repository
git remote -v
```

If it starts with `https://`, SSH would not be used at all.

Second, if Git, through SSH, is asking for a username/password, it means SSH defaults back to basic auth, instead of private key identity file.
That can be either because:

- the SSH URL is incorrect and does not start with `git@github.com:...` (but `myUser@github.com:...`, which is not valid)
- there is a [permission issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36687/7490) in your local `~/.ssh` folder